# Create a set containing every member

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to create at compile-time (or with constant time when run) a set with members of ordinal type `T` containing every *named* value of `T`?

In other words, how could I complement the empty set of a particular type?

```
type 
  TEnum = 
  ( 
    eA = 1,
    eB = 5,
    eC = 34 
  );
  TSet = set of TEnum;

const
  CSet: TSet = ~[]; // with ~ being my fictional set complement operator
```

Then `CSet` should contain only the *named* values `eA`, `eB`, and `eC`.

Of course this isn't a practical question, I'm just curious

---

**EDIT**

I didn't realize the behavior of enum types when declared with explicit, non-consecutive values. The enum still contains unnamed members to fill the gaps. Updated question to apply only to named members

Comment: CSet: TSet = [eA, eB, eC]

Comment: @user246408 it includes those elements even if they aren't named? e.g. you're saying `TSet` includes the element with ordinal value 17?

Comment: oh sheesh, is it too late to change my question to apply only to named members? :(

Comment: Not too late, but your enum contains every value between low and high

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is quite easy for enumerations that don't have specified values like

```
type 
  TEnum = 
  ( 
    eA,
    eB,
    eC 
  );
  TSet = set of TEnum;

const
  CSet: TSet = [eA..eC];
  CSet: TSet = [low(TEnum)..high(TEnum)];
```

---

However, with your `TEnum` defined as

```
type 
  TEnum = 
  ( 
    eA = 1,
    eB = 5,
    eC = 34 
  );
```

above will not work the way you expect. In your case `CSet` will contain all numerical values between low and high enum values (1 to 34).

The only way to get only `TEnum` values you have explicitly named is by using `CSet: TSet = [eA, eB, eC];`

This is by design as documented in [Simple Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Simple_Types#Enumerated_Types_with_Explicitly_Assigned_Ordinality)